# Changing names for all files in subdirectroies

Tags: bash, file-rename

I have a folder with a number of subfolders. Each of the subfolders consists of several files without extension.
I need to add extension .cel to each file in subfolders.

How can I do it using bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` to the rescue:

```
find /your/folder -type f -exec mv {} {}.cel \;
```

**Explanation**: `find` obtains all files inside the `/your/folder` structure. From all the results obtained, it performs the `mv` command. It makes the file `XXX` to be moved to `XXX.cel`, which is another way of renaming it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `rename` then using that with `find` should do the trick:

```
find . -type f -exec rename -v 's/$/\.cel/' {} \;
```